# Saving buttonIndex into object(NSNumber)

Tags: iphone, nsnumber

I am trying to save the selectedIndex of actionsheet into an object. But why does it always read 0?

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSNumber *type, *count;
    if ([actionSheet.title isEqualToString:@"Select Taxi Type"]) {
        if (buttonIndex !=3) {
            type = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:buttonIndex];
            UIActionSheet *taxiCountQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Taxi Count" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

            taxiCountQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
            taxiCountQuery.tag = actionSheet.tag;

            [taxiCountQuery showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];

            [taxiCountQuery release];
        }
    }
    else if ([actionSheet.title isEqualToString:@"Select Taxi Count"]){
        if (buttonIndex !=3) {
            NSLog(@"buttonIndex:%i", buttonIndex);
            count = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:buttonIndex];
            NSLog(@"type:%f", type); // always read 0
            NSLog(@"count:%f", count); // always read 0
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT - 2nd part

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSNumber *type = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
    if ([actionSheet.title isEqualToString:@"Select Taxi Type"]) {
        if (buttonIndex !=3) {
            type = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:buttonIndex];
            UIActionSheet *taxiCountQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Taxi Count" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
            taxiCountQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
            taxiCountQuery.tag = actionSheet.tag;

            [taxiCountQuery showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];

            [taxiCountQuery release];
        }
    }
    else if ([actionSheet.title isEqualToString:@"Select Taxi Count"]){
        if (buttonIndex !=3) {
            NSNumber *count = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:buttonIndex+1];
            NSLog(@"buttonIndex:%i", buttonIndex);
            count = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:buttonIndex +1];
           NSLog(@"type:%i", [type intValue]); // always read 0
            NSLog(@"count:%i", [count intValue]); // reads fine now
           [count release];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSNumber is an object that can hold basic types for storing in data structures like NSDictionary and NSArray. The %f in the NSLog is looking for a double.
This code should be giving you a warning.

If you do NSLog(@"%i",[type intValue]) you will get the right answer.

Comment: Somehow just changing the NSLog statement crashes.

Comment: You'll need to actually initialize type to something. You aren't when it's in the second if block.

Comment: I have edited my question to include what I have edited but still could get 'type' to work.

Comment: Check out this screenshot. You're never setting type when it's in the "Select Taxi Count" part of the if block. http://screencast.com/t/6HyamhiFVH

Comment: I am actually displaying 2 actionsheet, one after the other. Select Taxi Type then Select Taxi Count. Wouldn't 'type' be set during the "Select Taxi Type" action sheet?

Comment: I solved the issue by moving the init statement to during viewDidLoad.

Comment: The object gets recreated every time the action sheet sheet gets picked. So when the Select Taxi Count sheet comes up, type never gets set.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this code.

```
NSNumber *numberNs = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:buttonIndex];
```

Hope this helps you.